# Suppose that G is abelian and that V is an irreducible CG module.

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that G is abelian and that V is an irreducible CG module. 
Let k exist in G.
Show that the map $\theta$$_k$:V -> V defined by $\theta$$_k$ $(v)=kv$ is a homomorphism for all v in V.

So I just need to show that $\theta$$_k$ (g.v) = g . ( $\theta$$_k$ .v)?

So $\theta$$_k$ (g.v) = k . (g.v)=(gk).v
And
g . ( $\theta$$_k$ .v)=g . (kv) =(gk).v

so the map is a homomorphism?

It felt to simple, so I am not sure this answer is correct.
Thanks

Comment: You mean "for all $v\in V$ is a homomorphism."

Answer (score 1):

That is enough to establish the map is $\Bbb C[G]$ "homogeneous," but you should also show that it is an additive map: that is, $\theta_k(v+w)=\theta_k(v)+\theta_k(w)$.

Comment: okay thanks for your help